# Execution time difference for a function in two schemas

Tags: sql, performance, execution

We have a fabrication database hosted on three instances. On instance 1 and instance 2 it is called FabDB and on instance 3 it is called CRDB.

In general it makes no difference in the data being retrieved using CRDB or FabDB for any table. I think the tables data is stored at a common place.

We wrote a function in one of the schemas of fabdb. We have granted all permissions and synonyms.

If we run the function from FabDb it completes in 3 seconds. But if we run it from CRDB it takes 580 seconds. I am not sure where  this is going wrong.

Comment: Could you post the execution plan for both servers?

Comment: Are these instances on the same server or separate? Also, is the function having to wait on resources when ran against CRDB or is it consistently in a running state?

Comment: @JohnSpecko The instances are spread across three different servers. To answer your other question, I ran this function in in SQL developer as part of a select statement and i faced the same issue

Comment: @RandallMathews I am really not sure if I can get execution plan for a function. I thought we can get it only for individual SQL Queries.

Comment: It was identified that difference in SGA is causing the delay.